# Someone is using the struct name as a variable name too. What does the code really say?

Tags: c++, naming-conventions

This morning we found an old chunk of code that was causing a library call to crash.

```
struct   fred
{
    int     a;
    int     b;
    int     c;
};

fred     fred[MAX_SIZE+1];

memset( fred, 0, sizeof(fred) * MAX_SIZE+1 );
```

It appears that the sizeof(fred) may have been the full array size, rather than the structure size, as it was overwriting a *great deal* of memory.

The fact that it compiled without warning on several different systems seemed odd.

**Is there a correct semantic for this case where the type and variable name are colliding?
or is this some sort of undefined behavior? or just a defect?**

Comment: **What does the code really say?**

It says somebody at your organization needs a stern talking to. Who thought that would be a good idea?

Comment: @rlbond - The coder is long gone, but his memory lingers on.

Comment: I find it interesting that such evil code would be posted by "EvilTeach"... :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Number one would be, don't do this as it's confusing - but you've already discovered this.

The variable hides the name of the struct, but you can still use `struct fred` to refer to the type.

e.g.

```
fred     fred[MAX_SIZE+1];

memset( fred, 0, sizeof(struct fred) * (MAX_SIZE+1) );
```

Alternatively, why not just use the size of the complete object. That way your `memset` call is robust in the face of changes to either the array size or type. You can do:

```
memset( fred, 0, sizeof fred );
```

You *must* have the parentheses when using a type id with `sizeof` but it's not needed when you use an object.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't this be sizeof(fred)*(MAX_SIZE+1) since your array is MAX_SIZE+1 long?

Comment: Yes. That certainly is additional evil. +1

Answer (score 2):

The latest declaration takes precedence:

> `[C++03: 9.1/2]:` A class definition introduces the class name into the scope where it is defined and hides any class, object, function, or other declaration of that name in an enclosing scope (3.3). **If a class name is declared in a scope where an object, function, or enumerator of the same name is also declared, then when both declarations are in scope, the class can be referred to only using an *elaborated-type-specifier*** (3.4.4).

An *elaborated-type-specifier* is when you stick `struct` or `class` at the front of the type; this effectively disambiguates it, though, strictly speaking, and due to the above cited rule, the lookup was never really ambiguous in the first place.

So:

```
void foo()
{
   struct bar {};
   bar bar[5];

   memset(bar, 0, sizeof(bar));
   //             ^^^^^^^^^^^
   //                  5

   memset(bar, 0, sizeof(struct bar));
   //             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   //                  1
}

// (NB. Exact sizes may differ; 1 and 5 given as relative examples only)
```

The fact that this is all well-defined is one reason that you didn't get a warning. Still, I'd *hope* that an intelligent compiler would spot your code as a possible programmer mistake — rationalising about why some given implementation does or does not emit some given warning in some non-mandated case, though, is largely folly.

Comment: Weird, why doesn't this have more upvotes? It cites the standard! =)

Answer (score 1):

When you define the variable, it hides the name of the type, so yes, when you do `sizeof(fred)`, you're getting the size of the array, not the size of the struct. it's pretty easy to verify this by simply printing out `sizeof(fred)`.

The short answer, however, is just: "don't do that."

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of run-time sized cases, the typical idiomatic way to use `memset` (as well as `memcpy`, `malloc`, etc.) is to do

```
memset(dst_ptr, 0, sizeof *dst_ptr);
```

or, equivalently,

```
memset(&dst_object, 0, sizeof dst_object);
```

Which is how it should have been used in this case as well

```
memset(&fred, 0, sizeof fred);
```

and the problem with the name conflict would not arise. The `memset(fred, 0, sizeof fred)` variant will work as well.